# How to set Responsive Filemanager to return absolute url in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, responsive-filemanager

Im using Responsive Filemanager v9.3 with TinyMCE

I need to absolute url for inserting image url or any files. But it return relative path.

I need to set image src like `<img src="http://domain.com/files/slide.jpg">` but it return `<img src="../files/slide.jpg">`

My Config:

```
$base_url= 'http://domain.com';
$upload_dir = '/files/';
$current_path = '../../files/';
$thumbs_base_path = '../thumbs/';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add following code to TinyMCE init.

```
        tinymce.init({
            relative_urls: false
        });
```

Comment: I had this problem and did this but my files are inside /md (like /md/source) but it returns /source

Answer (score 9):

If you want the complete absolute path (http://www/example.com/source/image.png) but the base_url is missing (/source/image.png) you can include it by using:

```
tinymce.init({
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host : false
});
```